# Dump HTML of page including iframes

Tags: html, iframe, selenium, phantomjs, browser-automation

I'd like to dump the HTML contents of a web page, including the HTML of iframes included inside the `<iframe>` elements. The Chrome Developer Tools "Elements" tab is capable of showing iframe embedded in this way.

When I say "dump the HTML contents" I'm interested in browser automation tools like Selenium or PhantomJS. Do any of these tools have this capacity built in?

For example, the HTML dump I'd like of [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/3bgq1zvo/embedded/result/) should include the HTML source of [this embedded page](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/cheatsheet.php).

Answer (score -1):

You can use phantomjs to achieve this

Here is a code snippet from the phantom js server code.

```js
var system = require('system');
var url = system.args[1] || '';
if(url.length > 0) {
  var page = require('webpage').create();  
  page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
      var delay, checker = (function() {
        var html = page.evaluate(function () {
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
          if(body.getAttribute('data-status') == 'ready') {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
          }
        });
        if(html) {
          clearTimeout(delay);
          console.log(html);
          phantom.exit();
        }
      });
      delay = setInterval(checker, 100);
    }
  });
}
```

on the html you use the "data-status" attribute to let phantomjs know when the page is ready if the html belongs to you . The other option would be to use a nice timeout if the html page does not belong to you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How do you get the source of the iframes into the page? Also, waiting for "page ready" is unnecessary, because the `page.open` callback is only then called when the page is ready.

Comment: You can Get the Url that the Iframe points to from the html variable then you load using that and open that page and get the iframes content like that using the url and the page.open() again on the iframes url and then replaceing the whole iframe tag in the html variable containing all the html , do you want me to code if for you aswell. Maybe open a fiddle?

Comment: You seem to have a pretty good idea. You can add this to your answer (at which point I remove the downvote) and maybe support this by adding code which does this (at which point I will upvote if it is correct).