# Phantomjs throwing "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them" error even after setting the correct useragent

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, frames

When I tried to open one of our internal application's webpage(which works on IE8) using phantomjs, 'page.content' is showing below html message. However, page.render("test.png") is showing the completely loaded page.
I have set the page.settings.useragent to Why is the discrepancy between .render() and .content? How to debug/resolve this issue?

HTML output:

```
<html>
<frameset id="mainFrameSet" border="0" frameborder="yes" framespacing="1" rows="37px,*" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bordercolor="#cdcdcd">
    <frame name="header" src="<src>" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" bordercolor="#cdcdcd" marginwidth="0" noresize="" scrolling="no" bor
der="0">
    <frame frameborder="0" border="0" name="main" id="main" src="<src>" bordercolor="#cdcdcd" scrolling="auto" leftmargin="0">
    <noframes>
        &lt;BODY&gt;
        &lt;P&gt;This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.&lt;/P&gt;
        &lt;/BODY&gt;
    </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

my code:

```
var page = require("webpage").create(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.XSSAuditingEnabled = true;
page.viewportSize = { width: 1366, height: 768 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)';
//Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)
//Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
//Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34
//Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
//Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)
//Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
//SpecialAgent

    //Load Login Page
    page.open("<URL>");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    enterLoginCredentials();
        },10000);

  function enterLoginCredentials (){
    //Enter Credentials
    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log("Loading login page..:  " + url);
      var uName = document.getElementsByName("username");
      var uPass = document.getElementsByName("password");
      uName[0].value="username";
      uPass[0].value="password";
    });
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    clickLogin();
        },1000);
  }

  function clickLogin(){
    //Login
    page.evaluate(function() {
    var formSubmit = document.forms["loginForm"];
    formSubmit.submit();
    });
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    search();
        },10000);
    page.render("LRMLogin111.png");
  }

function search(){
    page.render("Homepage.png");
    console.log("Homepage "+page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pages use frames even today. In contrast to the developer tools of your browser of choice PhantomJS doesn't include the DOM of the child frames in the main DOM. See for example this question which tries to overcome this: [Dump HTML of page including iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663357/dump-html-of-page-including-iframes).

If you actually want to print and manipulate the child frames you have to switch to them. This is usually done with [`page.switchToFrame`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html). To get the content, you can log the [`page.frameContent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/frame-content.html) property.

```
page.render("Homepage.png");
console.log(page.frameContent); // same as page.content here
console.log("############################################");
page.switchToFrame(0); // first child frame
console.log(page.frameContent); // different as page.content here
console.log("############################################");
page.switchToMainFrame(); // switch back up before switching to the second child
page.switchToFrame(1); // second child frame
console.log(page.frameContent); // different as page.content here
console.log("############################################");
page.switchToMainFrame();
console.log(page.frameContent); // same as page.content here
```

Comment: While switching to the frame, I am getting below error- ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ActiveXObject. How to resolve this error?

Comment: You're probably using a web site which only works on Internet Explorer. You will need to provide an implementation of `ActiveXObject` in a `page.evaluate` from the `page.onInitialized` callback.