# How to get full interpreted html source with iframes in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, phantomjs

With PhantomJS, I want to print the html source of a webpage like Firebug does. Interpreted with iframes.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://google.com', function () {
  console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit(); 
});
```

This only seem to shows the interpreted HTML without iframes html. And use evaluate can't help because my iframes are in another domain so I think javascript with not have access to them.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you will have to write it yourself. Earlier code request: [Dump HTML of page including iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663357/dump-html-of-page-including-iframes)

Comment: Thank you but I already made this kind of solution. It downloads again the iframes (like others page.open) but it is "a waste" since PhantomJS is a full web browser so must have already downloaded this content. But this information may be hiden to us in the interpreter.

Comment: There should be no need to download the iframes as you can simply switch to every iframe and get its content.

Comment: Yes, I have found why I can't make it work, see edit of my question.

Answer (score 6):

I found that going through frames to get content did not work because `page.framesCount` in phantomjs counts only the child frames and not the main frame. Here is working code to display the HTML of all frames:

```
// Apparently framesCount doesn't include the main frame so add 1
var frameCount = page.framesCount + 1
var html = page.frameContent + '\n\n'
for (var i = 1; i < frameCount; ++i) {
  page.switchToFrame(i)
  html += page.frameContent + '\n\n'
}
```

One last important thing, if you don't want the source but want to access the iframe DOM even if it's in another domain do it like this:

```
phantomjs --web-security=no
```

The code to access the iframe body is:

```
var i = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
var body = i[0].contentWindow.document.body
```

Comment: Even with --web-security=no it appears the frames are still only tied to the domain. Additionally, is there a way to get the rendered source of the iframe?

Comment: --web-security=false